# Condition where orthogonal rows imply orthogonal columns.

Tags: matrices

Given a square matrix with orthogonal, non-zero rows (that are not orthonormal); must the rows each have exactly and only one non-zero element in order for the columns of the matrix to be orthogonal as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some complements:

As you may have seen, there are a lot of counterexample.
If you want one with the norm of the rows not all equal, just take
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Your claim is true only if the norm of the rows are all distinct. In fact, in that case, you have (since $A$ is invertible)
$$
AA^T =D \quad A^TA=D' \implies A^{-1}DA = D'
$$
where $D$ and $D'$ are diagonal matrices, so $A$ is forced to be almost a permutation matrix.

Answer (score 3):

No, for example 
$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
$ or more generally 
$\begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
-y & x
\end{pmatrix}
$ for $x,y \neq 0$.

Comment: Erk. Just realized I had downvoted this instead of upvoting... (and can't change that unless the question gets edited.)

Comment: I'll edit my answer by adding a "." at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Rotation matrices
$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$$
are a counterexample.